# Parentheses Balanced or Not ! In C ++

Tags: c++, josephus

I'm having some problem with this algorithm of checking whether the string of Parentheses are  balanced or not.I have to take the input from a text file and show the output in another text file.I'm having trouble with this algorithm.Please help me to find out the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "stack.h"
#include "stack.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main() {
  StackType<char> c;
  ifstream inFile("parentheses.txt");
  ofstream outFile("report.txt");
  int i, N;
  char str[500];
  inFile >> N;
  inFile >> str;
  while (str[i]) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
      if ((str[i] == '(') || (str[i] == '{') || (str[i] == '[')) {
        c.Push(str[i]);
      } else if ((str[i] == ')') || str[i] == '}' || str[i] == ']') {
        if (c.isEmpty() == 1)
          outFile << "Parentheses are not Balanced" << endl;
        else if ((str[i] == ')' && str[i] == '(') ||
                 (str[i] == '}' && str[i] == '{') ||
                 (str[i] == ']' && str[i] == '[')) {
          c.Pop();
        } else
          outFile << "Parentheses are not Balanced" << endl;
      }
    }
    i++;
  }
  if (c.isEmpty() == 1)
    outFile << "Parentheses are Balanced" << endl;
  else
    outFile << "Parentheses are not Balanced" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the layout of your code. And post an example showing what is wrong.

Comment: On which part are you stuck? Unexpected result? Have you tried using a stepper to debug?

Comment: what is your constraint? when are your parenthesis balanced?

Comment: When you used the debugger, which line is causing problems?

Comment: `str[i] == ')' && str[i]  == '('` oh wow.

Comment: after the 2nd `outFile << "Parentheses are not Balanced" << endl;` there was a `, probably a typo from the previous edit, I removed it.

Comment: This code is giving me wrong output.So the algorithm is wrong.Another this is my code reads only 2 line of my string


my input text file contains


6
{ { ( [ ] [ ] ) } ( ) }
( [ ) ]   
[ [ { { ( ( ) ) } } ] ]
( ( ( ) ] ) )
[ { ( ) ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] ( ) { }

Answer (score 1):

I can say with some certainty that this:

```
if((str[i] == ')' && str[i]  == '(') || (str[i] == '}' && str[i] == '{') || (str[i] == ']' && str[i] == '['))
```

is incorrect, as it will always be false.  I'm assuming you mean something like:

```
if ((c.Top() == '(' && str[i] == ')' || ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never call 'Pop' at the moment, because you compare str[i] against itself, expecting it to be two different values.

Instead you should be comparing stri[i] against whatever is on the top of your stack.